# Regexpr, match string

Tags: javascript, regex

Got these strings:

```
var str1 = '3fDGuIu2fBpu6Fc45QY1fF',#13,'BaseQuantities',$,',(#2192,#2194,#2196,#2198,#2200,#2202,#2204,#2206)';

var str2 = 'IsExternal',$,ABCBOOLEAN(.T.),$';

var str3 = '(8.01,0.,-3.)'
```

I want a regexpr that matches this: `(#2192,#2194,#2196,#2198,#2200,#2202,#2204,#2206)` in str1 and this `(8.01,0.,-3.)` in str 3 .Nothing in `str2` should be matched.

I tried this:

```
/(,\s*)\((.*?)\)/g
```

Almost works but it matches `(.T.)` in str3.

So the rule is to only match if it begins with a `,` or if `(` is the first char of the string.

http://regexr.com/3dp99

Comment: What are the specifications? Why string 1 and 3 should match and the second one should not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is more or less exactly what you want: `(^|,)\(([^)]*)\)`

Or with non capturing first group: `(?:^|,)\(([^)]*)\)`

http://regexr.com/3dp9r

Comment: *more or less exactly* :')

Comment: :D I probably should have written that this regex succeeds with the given test set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\((?:#\d+,?|-?\d*\.\d*,?)+\)` see [Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/hL0tX6/1)

Comment: Great! I added a forth string that was matched, https://regex101.com/r/bT1wZ4/1. 'ThermalTransmittance',$,IFCTHERMALTRANSMITTANCEMEASURE(1.) . Possible to unmatch this as well?

Comment: @PerStröm: Are going to add more and more strings to the question? It is counterproductive. Just explain *what* you want to match and what not.

Comment: @PerStröm Why would you want to unmatch `1.` and yet match `0.`.  Wouldn't that be inconsistent?